# Stochastically perturbed fluid flow map ${\rm d}Φ_t(x_0)=u_t(Φ_t(x_0)){\rm d}t+ξ_t(Φ_t(x_0)){\rm d}W_t$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, fluid-dynamics, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $U$ be a separable Hilbert space
- $Q$ be a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $U$ with finite trace
- $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a $Q$-Wiener process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$

Moreover, let

- $d\in\left\{2,3\right\}$
- $\mathcal V_0\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded domain
- $u:[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ and $\Phi:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ with $${\rm d}\Phi_t(x_0)=u_t\left(\Phi_t\left(x_0\right)\right){\rm d}t+\xi_t\left(\Phi_t\left(x_0\right)\right){\rm d}W_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\text{ and }x_0\in\mathcal V_0\tag 1$$ for some $\xi:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d\to\operatorname{HS}(U_0,\mathbb R^d)$, where $\operatorname{HS}(U_0,\mathbb R^d)$ is the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ to $\mathbb R^d$

> The idea is that $\Phi_t(x_0)$ is the position at time $t\ge 0$ of a particle which started at position $x_0\in\mathcal V_0$ at time $0$. By $(1)$, the trajectory of each particle is perturbed by a random forcing.
>   Let's assume that the particle system is closed (i.e. no particle is destroyed and no new particle is created). Then, if $\xi=0$, it's clear that each $\Phi_t$ should be a bijection.
>   If $\xi\ne 0$, I somehow want to preserve that property. In particular, I want to be able to talk about the bounded domain $\mathcal V_t\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ occupied by the particle system at time $t\ge 0$. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked the book by Da Prato and Zabczyk (SDEs in infinite dimensions) or Kunita (stochastic flows)? I guess it depends on the regularity of the functions $u_t$ and indeed $\xi_t$. In the classical case when $W$ is a std. Wiener process, the family $\{\Phi_t(x)\}_{t>0}$ is a one.parameter semigroup of diffeomorphisms (at least when the coefficients are regular)

Comment: @Martingalo I've checked Da Prato, but that doesn't help. I don't see that $(\Phi_t(x_0))_{t\ge 0}$ has the semigroup property. Can you prove it?

Comment: It should be easy if the coefficients are Lipschitz. Just just have to compare $\Phi_t\Phi_s$ and $\Phi_{t+s}$ (use Grönwall). Or just simply show that both satisfy the same SDE and then it follows by uniqueness of solutions.

Comment: @Martingalo $\Phi_t\Phi_s$ is composition or multiplication?

Comment: @Martingalo Side note: I've applied the Itō formula to $u_t\left(\Phi_t\left(x_0\right)\right)$ and obtained the equation $(1)$ in [an other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774561/recast-the-scalar-spde-du-t%CE%A6-tx-f-t%CE%A6-txdt%E2%88%87-u-t%CE%A6-tx%E2%8B%85%CE%BE-t%CE%A6-txdw-t). This question is somehow related to that question. Maybe you can help there too.

Comment: Yes I meant composition of course. I think there is a typo in eq. (1) in that other question, some differential missing maybe. In any case if you apply Itô's formula on $u_t(\Phi_t(x))$ you won't get that. I think you forgot to take into account the quadratic variation. Unless it is included in what you call $f_t$.

Comment: @Martingalo Yes, it's included in $f_t$. I've simplified the equation, cause my main question is whether I can simply "drop the $\Phi_t(x)$" or not. I've added the missing differential. Let me shortly explain what I'm doing: I want to derive a stochastic version of the Navier-Stokes equations. $\Phi$ in $(1)$ can be considered as a "fluid flow map".

Comment: @Martingalo I want to assume that the trajectories of the particles, which are described by that map, are perturbed. At the end, I want to find a stochastic analogue of the "material derivative" by using an Itō formula. My problem is, that one usually considers SPDEs indexed by time only and as equations in a Hilbert space. But I obtain an equation which is indexed by both time and space.